# Mysql PDO timeouts on web requests, cli works perfect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection-timeout

We use a php script and mysql/pdo to connect to a db masterserver.
Recently we get a high percentage of users >10% where the web request dies because of a DB connection error with the message "Connection timed out".
The Exception is thrown during the creation of the PDO class in its constructor which is wrapped in a try/catch.

When I create a cli script that tries to connect to the same server, does a "SELECT 1" and closes the connection, I get 100% success rate.

When I ssh into the mysql shell of the db server and run `show processlist;` i see a lot of Sleeping connections that vanish once they reach 30 seconds lifetime.

I also monitored the SQL slowlog and nothing sticks out, a handful of queries that go beyond 5 seconds but with the number of requests that isnt something of note.

How do i go about debugging this?

Comment: try to increase the nbumber of possible connections max_connections = 100

Comment: @nbk i already increased them from 500 to 600, altough i dont see that many connections in the `show processlist;`, there are like 50 at the moment

Comment: there also limitations by the system that you use https://serverfault.com/a/533612